# What is the sign on the Delta Vega lithium cracking station?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

You see the sign in the background when Kirk et al beam down, in the pilot episode, "Where No Man Has Gone Before" but it is cut off.  I read "Galactic" and "Delta-Vega", but there is more...

What does it read in full?

[image]

Source:

https://www.shipbrook.net/jeff/raytrace/graphics/ref-dvga.jpg

Comment: This question could be improved with the inclusion of a sreenshot

Comment: Galactic Mining Company, presumably. Since it's their station

Comment: "Galactic Mining Company" or the abbreviated "CO".

Comment: Just noting that looks like it's from the 1966 broadcast version rather than the slightly altered 2007 remaster, which had point sources of light on the tanks and a lit-up room on the second floor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Memory Alpha has some information:

> The Galactic Mining Company was a business concern that operated the Delta-Vega Station, an unmanned lithium cracking station on the remote planet Delta Vega in 2265. (TOS: "Where No Man Has Gone Before")
>
> The name comes from a sign on the exterior wall of the facility shown in the episode. "Galactic Mining" is clearly visible in the close up, and the long shot, while not clear, suggests that it is followed by CO or Co (a common abbreviation for "Company").

https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Galactic_Mining_Company[1](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Galactic_Mining_Company)

I have seen images and/or a discussion somewhere on the internet recently.  If I could remember where, that might help settle the question.